# How can I print character constant correctly by using _printf_p function?

Tags: c, visual-studio, printf

VS contains a nonstandard function called `_printf_p`, which supports positional parameters in the format string. For example,

```
_printf_p ("%1$o %1$x %1$u\n", 123U);
```

is equivalent to

```
printf ("%o %x %u\n", 123U, 123U, 123U);
```

but when I tried to print character constants, something strange happens:

```
printf ("%#x %c\n", 'A', 'A');
```

is Okay, but

```
_printf_p ("%1$#x %1$c\n", 'A');
```

will return an error called "Debug assertion failed".

Why does this happen? How can I print a character constant correctly by using `_printf_p` function?

Comment: No clue, but I suspect in the last case, `'A'` cannot be type promoted to satisfy both `%x` and `%c` at the same time since the specifiers require an argument of different size (4-bytes and 1-byte).

Comment: If you have the CRT source code installed you can find the `is_positional_parameter_reappearance_consistent` function. Part of the comments at the top of it are `All appearances of a given parameter must be consistent (they must match in type and width).` I would guess it's failing here: `if (old_is_string != new_is_string || old_is_character != new_is_character)`

Comment: If my first guess was correct, you could be able to modify with `hhx` instead of `x` so that the hex-type expects a 1-byte hex value instead of a 4-byte value.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: For `c` an `int`, four bytes in this C implementation, is expected. No `printf` conversion can expect an eight-bit argument since all variable arguments are promoted to at least `int`. Further, the type of a character constant in C is `int`, and `c` is expected to accept them. However, for `x`, an `unsigned int` is expected.

Comment: What happens if you try only "%1$c"? (I cannot check, I avoid VS as much as possible.)

Comment: Only "%1$c" works. In addition, positional parameters is a nonstandard feature supported by VS only by using specific functions.

Comment: No — the `_printf_p()` function is emulating the POSIX standard [`printf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html).  Or, at least, the _`n$`_ notation is also used in POSIX `printf()`.  AFAIK, the POSIX specification pre-dates the MS implementation — the notation was defined no later than the 1997 POSIX standard ([`printf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fprintf.html)).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/printf-p-positional-parameters

Comment: `_printf_p ("%1$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');`, 

`_printf_p ("%2$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');`, 

`_printf_p ("%3$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');`, 

`_printf_p ("%3$c %2$c %1$c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');`

Only the first one and the last one have output